# How I can capture the event when the spinner don't change item

Tags: android, android-spinner

I need to capture the event when the spinner don't change item. This is my code:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
}
}
```

This code works when I change item in spinner. But when I always click on the select Item how I can capture this event? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you still doing something here? Is the question answered? Or should I close it?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple.
Impl. the OnItemClickListener for the Spinner.

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I obtain null pointer exception and this "cannot be used with a spinner."

Comment: As you can see the documentation I have linked is pointing to the Spinner Widget in the SDK. It includes the methode setOnItemClickListener and it is available since API Lvl 1. So your problems seams be somewhere else. Are you using Spinner from SDK? or a propetary one?

Comment: Also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSpinner.html is inerhiting setOnItemClickListener from AdapterView.